# Fix for "Nokogiri failed to build gem native extension"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, nokogiri

The command on my Mac

```
$ gem install nokogiri -v '1.7.1'
```

gives the error

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

I tried using

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
```

but it didn't help, I get the same error

Answer (score 2):

The fix was to use

```
xcode-select --install
```

and accept the GUI prompt that comes up about developer options.

Then the `gem install` and `bundle` commands worked.